# Cannot remove polyline in leaflet map

Tags: javascript, html, web, leaflet, frontend

I am currently using a leaflet map and drawing 2 polylines. What I want to do is that to be able to display only one of them at the time.

**My function for drawing the polylines looks as follows:**

```
function displaypolyline(message, id) {
  var polyline = 0;
  var polyline1 = 0;

  switch (id) {
    case '0':
      // message contain the gps cordinate 
      polyline = L.polyline(message, {
        color: '#3498db',
        noClip: false,
        smoothFactor: 0.5
      }).addTo(map);
      break;
    case '1':
      polyline1 = L.polyline(message, {
        color: '#00FFFF',
        noClip: false,
        smoothFactor: 0.5
      }).addTo(map);
      break;
    default:

  }
```

**The part where i invoke the function :**

```
var latlngs =[0]
///// i have parsed a json data to the variable object
for (var i=0; i<obj.length;i++)
 {
  latlngs[i]=[obj[i].gps_lat, obj[i].gps_lon]
  displaypolyline(latlngs , id);
  }
```

Until now that function displays the polylines.

Nevertheless, when I modify it as follows:

```
switch (id) {

  case '0':
    polyline = L.polyline(message, {
      color: '#3498db',
      noClip: false,
      smoothFactor: 0.5
    });
    map.removeLayer(polyline1); // to remove the second polyline
    break;

  case '1':
    polyline1 = L.polyline(message, {
      color: '#00FFFF',
      noClip: false,
      smoothFactor: 0.5
    });
    map.removeLayer(polyline); // to remove the first polyline 
    break;
  default:

}
```

**It outputs the following error:**

`"Uncaught TypeError: can't assign to property "_leaflet_id" on 0: not an object u https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js:5 removeLayer https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js:5"`

Can somebody please help me to find a solution to the error I am getting?

Comment: Could you format your code cause it is really difficult to read?

Comment: basecly my function take the massage that have the cordinates and draw the polyline1 but i want to draw polyline2 i want to erase the first polyline

Comment: It seems you are not adding the polylines to the map anywhere. Could you include that part or where the part you invoke `displaypolyline`?

Comment: i have added the code and yes i have added the polyline to the map with addTo(map)

Comment: each polyline correspand to a diiferent set of data

Comment: in the second part when you modify the function you are not adding any polyline to the map and immediately you are trying to remove it

Comment: i have added add.To(map) and i am trying to remove the other polyline the polyline1

Comment: Indeed you did in the first snippet. In the second that you said you modified you haven't

Comment: yes i know i am trying to edit the post but i couldn't